# В каких тегах html может содержаться ссылка на сторонний элемент?

Tags: html

Пишу программу, которая будет выкачивать сайт (создавать его локальную копию, сохраняя все файлы и повторяя структуру сайта). Я плохо знаю HTML.

Вопрос: где в html могут содержаться ссылки на сторонние ресурсы, кроме  следующих тегов

1. <a href = 'ссылка ...>
2. <img src = 'ссылка'...>
3. <script src = 'ссылка'...>

Comment: Добро пожаловать на  StackOverflow. "Пишу программу, ... выкачивать сайт. ... плохо знаю HTML." - изучите HTML.

Comment: @Igor, [be-nice](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: <a href = 'ссылка ...>

Comment: @Grundy - обратите внимание на "Добро пожаловать"

Comment: <link href="...">

Comment: [COMPLETE list of HTML tag attributes which have a URL value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725156/complete-list-of-html-tag-attributes-which-have-a-url-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для определения нужного списка элементов, нужно посмотреть таблицы допустимых атрибутов для [HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/index/attributes.html) и для [HTML5](http://w3c.github.io/html/fullindex.html#attributes-table) и выбрать с нужным типом.

Итак в HTML4:

- `<a href=url>`
- `<applet codebase=url>`
- `<area href=url>`
- `<base href=url>`
- `<blockquote cite=url>`
- `<body background=url>`
- `<del cite=url>`
- `<form action=url>`
- `<frame longdesc=url>` и `<frame src=url>`
- `<head profile=url>`
- `<iframe longdesc=url>` и `<iframe src=url>`
- `<img longdesc=url>` и `<img src=url>` и `<img usemap=url>`
- `<input src=url>` и `<input usemap=url>`
- `<ins cite=url>`
- `<link href=url>`
- `<object classid=url>` и `<object codebase=url>` и `<object data=url>` и `<object usemap=url>`
- `<q cite=url>`
- `<script src=url>`

HTML 5 добавляет несколько новых (и, похоже, не использует некоторые из вышеперечисленных):

- `<audio src=url>`
- `<button formaction=url>`
- `<command icon=url>`
- `<embed src=url>`
- `<html manifest=url>`
- `<input formaction=url>`
- `<source src=url>`
- `<video poster=url>` и `<video src=url>`

Могут использоваться не обязательно простые адреса:

- `<object archive=url>` или `<object archive="url1 url2 url3">`
- `<applet archive=url>` или `<applet archive=url1,url2,url3>`
- `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="seconds; url">`

В дополнение, атрибут `style` может содержать css определения с одним или несколькими адресами. Например:  `<div style="background: url(image.png)">`

<sub>перевод [ответа на аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725168/2881286)</sub>

Comment: о, спасибо за перевод!

Comment: Прекрасно. Думаю большую часть использовать не придется.  Но многие очевидно понадобятся.